# Как динамически менять байты в картинке?

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5, pyqt

У меня есть картинка на заднем фоне, я хочу менять его байт код (как в hed editor) прямо во время работы программы, по нажатию кнопки. Возможно ли это? Я видел варианты, где можно получить в переменную байты из картинки, возможно ли менять их и сохранять в картинку обратно? 
Пример кода, где получают байты

```
    self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("realback.jpg"))

    pixmap = self.label.pixmap()

    ba = QtCore.QByteArray()
    buff = QtCore.QBuffer(ba)   
    buff.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly) 
    ok = pixmap.save(buff, "JPG")
    assert ok
    pixmap_bytes = ba.data()
    ba[24] = ba[:2] + ba[3:] + ' '
    print (pixmap_bytes)
    print(type(pixmap_bytes))


    ba = QtCore.QByteArray(pixmap_bytes)
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
    ok = pixmap.loadFromData(ba, "JPG")
    assert ok
    print(type(pixmap))

    self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

картинка используется так

```
class WindowTwo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(WindowTwo, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setFixedSize(1300, 800)
        self.setStyleSheet(open("style.qss", "r").read())
```

style.qss:

```
QMainWindow{
  background-image: url(realback1.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите сделать. Объясните пожалуйста лучше.

Comment: мне нужен datamosh эффект на фото, который появляется по нажатиям кнопок. Достичь этого можно меняя hex Code картинки. В qt  я могу получить код этой картинки в виде байтов, вопрос как изменить эти байты так чтобы это отобразилось на картинке